# Transaction between JMS queues

Tags: spring-integration

I have a scenario, where Queue 1 starts transaction with database and puts message into Queue 2 through outbound channel adapter.
If some exception occurs in Queue 2 I should roll back in Queue 1 as well.
Example code would be helpful.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. As far as I know queues don't start transactions. I don't want to speculate, but we should start to talk on the same language to come up with the solution together. You might consider to read this for better understanding mixed concerns transaction model: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html. Also that would be great to get a code exactly from you. Nobody here is going to do work for you.

Comment: Hi Artem, I have JMS message driven channel adapter that reads message from Queue 1, after some processing with the message puts message into Queue 2 using outbound channel adapter. Using message driven channel adapter I read message from Queue 2, in case of exception how do i rollback even the processing from Queue1. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have JMS message driven channel adapter that reads message from Queue 1, after some processing with the message puts message into Queue 2 using outbound channel adapter. Using message driven channel adapter I read message from Queue 2, in case of exception how do i rollback even the processing from Queue1.

You can't do that - they are separate transactions.

The second inbound adapter won't get the message until the first transaction commits.